# Issue with requesting Steam api Bukson

Tags: python, request, steam, steam-web-api

Good day !

To work with the Steam marketplace, I use the Steampy library from [Bukson](https://github.com/bukson/steampy).

It did not have the function I needed to create the `itemordershistogram` request, so I created it myself in the `market.py` file.
The problem is that the server responds with a `400` error, saying that the request was incorrectly composed.
I created the function similarly to others, so I can’t understand what the problem is ...

I am attaching the code with my function from `market.py`:

```
@login_required
def fetch_orders_histogram(self) -> dict:
    url = SteamUrl.COMMUNITY_URL + '/market/itemordershistogram/'
    params = {'country': 'RU',
              'language': 'russian',
              'currency': 1,
              'item_nameid': 14962984,
              'two_factor': 0}
    response = self._session.get(url, params=params)
    if response.status_code == 429:
        raise TooManyRequests("You can fetch maximum 20 prices in 60s period")
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise ApiException("http error code: %s" % response.status_code)
    return response.json()
```

And here is the code from `Python`:

```
from steampy.client import SteamClient
import time

steam_client = SteamClient('api-key')
steam_client.login("log", "pass", "steam_guard.json")

is_session_alive = steam_client.is_session_alive()

if(is_session_alive):
    print("Successfully logged in")
else:
    print("Error")

time.sleep(3)

resp = steam_client.market.fetch_orders_histogram()
print(resp)
```

After executing the code, it gives an error:

> steampy.exceptions.ApiException: http error code: 400

If you execute the request through the browser, then everything works as it should...

> https://steamcommunity.com/market/itemordershistogram?country=RU&language=russian&currency=1&item_nameid=14962984&two_factor=0

Friends, tell me, please, what is wrong in my request?
What to fix?

Thank you very much in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the trailing `/` from your URL.

Line 3 should read:
`url = SteamUrl.COMMUNITY_URL + '/market/itemordershistogram'`